# Dual Hover Effect - Change Image and Show Text in static position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an effect where on a mouse hover the image will change but also show text in another position. Basically I have 4 icon links, each having their own Text title. I want the text to show on the right side of the page when the mouse hovers over top. I can get the image to change but the text keeps changing position when the browser changes sizes. Is there a way to keep the text in the same position at all times?

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do: http://www.getthefive.com/

And here is my code so far:

CSS:

```
#monkey {
background-image: url('link');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height: 60px;
width: 50px;
}

#monkey:hover {
background-image: url('link');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#monkey .text {
position:fixed;
top:50px;
left:1100px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#monkey:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="monkey">
<p class="text">monkey</p>
</div>
```

THank you!!

Comment: its works fine ..  this a ploy so that people would visit your site.  find a better way to advertise man.

Comment: no not trying to advertise. When the browser minimizes or is smaller, the position of the text keeps moving? But I want to keep it in the same spot no matter what size browser it is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your only problem is that the text position doesn't adjust when you resize your browser. Try using `position:relative` instead of `position:fixed`